# How to display a placeholder image in a list box that have bonded data?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding, windows-phone

On windows phone 8 I have made a list box bandied with a web server data which are an image and a text sometimes the server returns only text as their are no image uploaded by the user. I need to display a placeholder image.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding places}" Name="mrx" Margin="0,10,0,0" Loaded="mrx_Loaded">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate >
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,10,8">
         <StackPanel  Margin="10,0,10,8">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="40"/>
           <Image Source="{Binding url}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
         </StackPanel>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here how I access url:

```
public BitmapImage h { get; set; }
public BitmapImage url
{
   get { return h; }
   set
   {
     if (h == null)
     {
       h.UriSource = new Uri("profile-placeholder.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

What are you trying to get?

Do you want to just use predefine image if there is no url from web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to me you can try 2 options

1) make a image failed event of the image and when its called then set the default image as source.

2) put the image view inside a grid with background as the default image so if url comes then it will overlap the default image and show you user image and if it fails then the background of the image will be there as default image.

I hope this might help ......

Comment: in image failed event i can not access image name as it is on listbox

Comment: i can not understand idea of grid a code snippet will be very good

Comment: you can acces the name of the image view using sender in the in the imagefailed event..   like var a =  sender as Image and then set a.source = your default image. this will work for you...

Answer (score 1):

If your `h == null` when there is no image returned then there is easier way to do what you want - use `TargetNullValue` in Binding:

```
<Image Source="{Binding url, TargetNullValue='/Example;component/Resources/placeholder.png'}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

In above case be sure to set BuildAction of `placeholder.png` as `Resource`. (`Example` here is your project name, `Resources` is a path to the file). You can also bind directly to your `h` in this case.

If you insist on using designed property then:

I'm not sure how the rest of your code looks like, but but when you have defined binding like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding url}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

When the item is being loaded the `Getter` of `url` is fired. So using `Setter` to repleace `null` with `Bitmapimage` won't help here (of course if you are not running `Setter` somewhere else, but defining `Setter` without `value` - kind a weird, implement it different or provide separate method.

Check if that would help:

```
public BitmapImage url
{
    get
    {
        if (h == null)
          return new BitmapImage() { UriSource = new Uri("/Projectname;component/path/profile-placeholder.gif", UriKind.Relative) };
        return h;

    }
}
```

Setting `UriSource` depends also how your file is defined in your project (Build Action), you can take a look [here](http://zzerk.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/loading-a-local-bitmap-into-a-windows-phone-application/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a default image in your assets. Set this image path string as a default value to the "url" that you use for binding. and when you get a web response and parse it, check if there is a valid url path string for an image. If there is a valid url string parsed for the image, then assign it to "url" field else If there is no valid url string for the image, do not set it to the url field. The"url" string field will any way contain the default image that you set.
Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: the url is of type bitimage

Comment: then create a bitimage with the url path of the default image and set it. If you get a non empty image field from the WS response, then again create a bitmap image out of this new url, and set it.

secondly you could go this way.

Create a separate string field which will get the WS response url path for the image. Initialize it to default path. and change it to new response path if WS has image url.
once this string value ahs been set correctly, call the set for the bitimage and initialize it with this string property.

Answer (score 0):

See [Conditional text formatting XAML WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905195/conditional-text-formatting-xaml-wp8)

You should bind to url and set conditional trigger if url is null

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image Source = "{Binding url} " Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

Here, instead of binding image source to URL directly, bind it to property having URL as a global variable and initiate URL to placeholder URL.

Example:

```
private string yourURL= "/Resources/Images/placeholder.png";

public string YourURL
{
    get
    {
        return yourURL;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != yourURL)
        {
            yourURL= value;                   
        }
    }
}
```

and statement will be like:

```
<Image Source="{Binding YourURL}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

Comment: i have made it oready in that way but url is of type bitimage

Comment: Then simply replace string in my code with your Bitmap object,and assign a bitmap object to it.

Like:
BitmapImage img= new BitmapImage();
FileStream _stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);
img.SetSource(_stream);

Comment: please read my answer carefully ,you will need to assign BitmapImage not string like as i shown.hope this helps.

Comment: that was my first idea but i can not assign string to bitimage i will edit my post to make it clear

Comment: So,here "h" should not be a property and just initialize it to some default BitmapImage from your resource folder,so in set of "url" property it will get replaced.